# C# DateTime - How to check Time part is NULL?

Tags: c#, datetime, null

Is there any easy way to check to see if the time part of the `DateTime` value is NULL other than checking hour is 0, min is 0 and sec is 0?

Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

I find this very readable:

```
var isTimeNull = (myDateTime.TimeOfDay == TimeSpan.Zero);
```

Comment: Thanks - is better than `.ToString.Equals("00:00:00")` :)

Comment: This checks if it is zero, which is a different concept to something being null

Comment: I believe this will fail if the time of day is precisely midnight.

Answer (score 15):

Here are my takes:

```
var isTimeNull = myDateTime.Date == myDateTime;
var isTimeNull = myDateTime.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds == 0;
```

And technically, time is not null, it's just not set.

Comment: Thanks Anton and let me try this.

Comment: How's that different from it being midnight?

Comment: I went with myDateTime.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds logic.  In my case, I have 2 dates (start date and end date). Based on whether the time component is filled, I change Oracle to_date() function. It works like a charm in all cases except one case where the user is trying to search for records exactly at the midnight (12 AM) on both date values. Thanks Anton.

Comment: @DavidKemp: Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: @testing maybe a different library, like Noda Time, that allows you to express dates and times as separate concepts  - http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/userguide/core-types.html

Answer (score 3):

DateTime does not support the concept of null for just the time component. Either the whole DateTime object is null (if using the nullable version), or both the date and time are non-null. If you don't specify the time component it will default to 0 (midnight).

Answer (score 2):

To avoid divisions and floating point accuracy issues use:

```
var isMidnight = myDateTime.TimeOfDay.Ticks == 0;
```